# Custom Web Authentication

Tags: security, session, cookies, session-cookies

I want to write a custom auth flow for a web app I am creating using go for the api and react for the ui.

My thought is to have a db table for users  with some general user info and a table for sessions with a user ID, session id, and expiration.

On login I will create a new row in the session table for the user and then set a secure http only cookie with the session ID. My middleware will lookup the session and validate it on request.

If the frontend needs user info it will make a request to a /me endpoint to return the user info associated with the session.

On logout I will remove the session from the db and remove unset the cookie in the browser.

Does this sound like a secure method for authentication? Or are there any concerns that I am not thinking of when it comes to this approach?

I haven't started implementing this and I think it will be very easy to implement. I'm just not a security export and wanted to see if someone who knows much more about this than I do could weigh in.

Comment: What you described is a plain old server-side session. Everything depends on the details. Sure, the concept is secure, but there are so many implementation details that can go wrong that the best practice is you should not implement this yourself. The language/framework you are using will surely have this (though I'm not very familiar with Go). Just to name a few, insufficient entropy, insecure random source, insecure session id storage, different forms of session fixation, session id storage flaws in the client... This is _by far_ not a comprehensive list of potential vulnerabilities.

Comment: @GaborLengyel this is really just as a learning opportunity for myself. But the trickiest part was storing the session info on the client. That's why I decided to use a secure http only cookie and not store user data in the cookie. Instead fetch the signed in user info and store it in the client state.